# table with two nullable foreign keys join results into single column

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2012

Sorry if title isn't very descriptive. I have a table like this example, and am using sql server 2012:

```
PersonId | PetID
```

and want to join it to the following two tables

```
PersonId | PersonName | PersonAsset

AnimalId | AnimalName | Animal Asset
```

So the end result is:

```
PersonId | PetId | Name | Asset
-------------------------------
1          null    Dave   1
null       1       Fido   2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The output you require can be achieved by using a LEFT JOIN for your two tables and [ISNULL](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms184325.aspx) for the required fields.

For example (assuming the first table is named 'common'):

```
SELECT common.PersonId,
       common.PetId,
       ISNULL(person.PersonName, animal.AnimalName) AS Name,
       ISNULL(person.PersonAsset, animal.AnimalAsset) AS Asset
FROM common
LEFT JOIN person ON common.PersonId = person.PersonId
LEFT JOIN animal ON common.AnimalId = animal.AnimalId
```